# spyder: Windows permission errors when saving script

Tags: windows, spyder

We've been trying to get spyder 5.1.5 to work inside a windows server environment (version 2012 and 2016). Before We've been using Spyder 3.3.6 successfully, but we want to upgrade to get "black/autopep8" autoformatting.

We have this distributed CIFS-like shared drive inside this server that has some strict permissions (but my username definitely has read/write/modify access at the level where the script is).
Unfortunately, when I try to get spyder to SAVE my code (and autoformat  using black), I get the following (trimmed) error below. Basically spyder cannot save due to a permission error that doesn't make sense to me.

`2021-12-08 18:23:52,005 [DEBUG] [spyder.plugins.completion.providers.languageserver.client] -> python Response error: {'code': -32602, 'message': "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '\\\\\\\\data-dist\\\\DataVol_014\\\\group\\\\users\\\\myusername\\\\myscript.py'", 'data': {'traceback': ['  File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py37-dev\\lib\\site-packages\\pylsp_jsonrpc\\endpoint.py", line 116, in consume\n    self._handle_request(message[\'id\'], message[\'method\'], message.get(\'params\'))\n', '`

Troubleshooting this further, I certainly have read/write/modify access to the following levels of this path:

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\users\myusername\myscript.py

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\users\myusername\

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\users\

However, I cannot even view this level:

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\

Still this does not make sense to me. I don't understand why spyder would need this level of access.
Any help/guidance is appreciated.
The error certainly goes away if I copy the script to a local drive on said server and the black autoformatting works as expected.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you able to load, make changes and save the file inside Spyder's editor?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, I can load but I cannot save the file inside Spyder's editor.
I have a similar problem with `git init` as well, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293003/git-init-permission-denied-if-no-access-to-part-of-the-path)

Comment: Then I'd say the problem lies in the way your directory is mounted or how it's exposed as a file system on Windows. I mean, it seems that makes Spyder and git think it's not writable somehow.

Comment: I should clarify that this remote drive is mounted using something called "softlink" (I don't know how closely related to linux symlinks they are...). The access privileges with the softlink are much more permissive. In fact that's how I'm able to load the script in the first place.
Unfortunately, internally to git and spyder, the softlink is replaced with the actual path and the permissions suddenly are all wrong...

Comment: @CarlosCordoba the other curious thing is that applications like Emacs or even Spyder 3.3.X have no problems whatsoever, even though, emacs, in particular explicitly expands the "softlink"

Comment: We've changed a lot of things since Spyder 3, so it's hard to tell. For instance, we added atomic writes on save to avoid possible corruptions in Spyder 4, which could be problematic in your setup.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, I did a bit more testing and Spyder is fine. It saves the file correctly. If I change the autoformatting to `autopep8` everything works quite well. Looks like the permission errors occur with `black` only.