# git init permission denied if no access to part of the path

Tags: windows, git

We've been trying to get git to work inside a windows server environment (version 2012 and 2016). It works mostly well, but our new user data storage moved to this CIFS-like shared drive (instead of local drives) and `git init` has permission trouble (trying this with git 2.29.2)

These are the steps to reproduce:
I have some code in this shared drive:

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\users\myusername\mycode\

So I navigate there with Windows file explorer and then right-click to call `git bash` here.
Git bash opens and then when I type `git init`, I get the following error:

> fatal: Invalid path '//data-dist/DataVol_014/group': Permission denied

We certainly have read/write/modify access to the following levels of this path

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\users\myusername\mycode\

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\users\myusername\

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\users\

However, I CANNOT even view these levels:

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\group\

> \\data-dist\DataVol_014\

And can ONLY view here:

> \\data-dist\

Any clues how to get this to work?

Comment: Map a drive so that git stops searching for parent .git and .gitignore things at the root of where you mapped the drive?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, yes, this workaround is good, but it's just an extra step to take and these servers are used by many users with a large variety of skills

Comment: Hmm, that's not straightforward to reproduce. On Linux, `chmod 100` would give me a folder I could cd into but not see. How do you do that on Windows? For what it's worth, `git init` worked fine in a similar setup on Linux, so this is most certainly a Windows-only issue, so it's good you tagged it `windows`.

Comment: @joanis I think that's the problem, I cannot `cd` into the `DataVol` and `group` levels. I'm not sure how they did this, since this is owned by our IT support. I believe the technology they use is related to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/s2d-hyper-converged?view=sc-vmm-2019)

Comment: Well, I think you might be stuck with the drive mapping solution, I don't see a way around it. If this is a common problem and your colleagues are not comfortable with that, you could request that IT do that drive mapping for everyone by default? (I work in a large organization, so yes, I do realize this might be the kind of suggestion that would never fly, but still...)